# R: Object not found inside a user-defined function, and unexpected {

Tags: r, function

I have a function with one argument that's supposed to be a 3-column data-frame.

```
probfinal<-function(y){
  x<-c(0,1,3)
  prev<-numeric(20)
  for(i in 1:length(y[,1]){
    prev[i]<-y[i,3]+sum(sample(x,38-y[i,2],replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.4,0.2,0.4)))
  }
  ligprev<-cbind(y,prev)
  return(ligprev)
}
```

I have two errors:

```
Error: unexpected '{' in:
"  prev<-numeric(20)
  for(i in 1:length(y[,1]){"
```

and

```
Error: object 'y' not found
```

And then other errors related to the mentioned ones.

Where's the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please give an example of what y looks like.  You are missing a )  in the for line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is missing a bracket:

```
probfinal<-function(y){
  x<-c(0,1,3)
  prev<-numeric(20)
  for(i in 1:length(y[,1])**)**{
    prev[i]<-y[i,3]+sum(sample(x,38-y[i,2],replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.4,0.2,0.4)))
  }
  ligprev<-cbind(y,prev)
  return(ligprev)
}
```

I marked it with two asterisks

Comment: Alright, I should pay more attention next time xd. Thanks.

Comment: No Problem. Can you mark the question as solved then?